# Mongoose can't search by number field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema that has an `id` field that is set to a `string`. When I use `collection.find({id: somenumber})` it returns nothing.

I've tried casting `somenumber` to a string and to a number. I've tried sending `somenumber` through as a regex. I've tried putting `id` in quotes and bare... I have no idea what's going on. Any help and input would be appreciated.

```
Toys.js

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var toySchema = new Schema( {
    id: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    price: Number
    } );
```

My index.js is as such

```
app.use('/findToy', (req, res) => {
    let query = {};

    if (req.query.id)
        query.id = req.query.id;

    console.log(query);

    // I've tried using the query variable and explicitly stating the object as below. Neither works.
    Toy.find({id: '123'}, (err, toy) => {
        if (!err) {
            console.log("i'm right here, no errors and nothing in the query");
            res.json(toy);
        }
        else {
            console.log(err);
            res.json({})
        }
    })
```

I know that there is a Toy in my mongoDB instance with `id: '123'`.  If I do `Toy.find()` it returns:

```
[{"_id":"5bb7d8e4a620efb05cb407d2","id":"123","name":"Dog chew toy","price":10.99},
{"_id":"5bb7d8f7a620efb05cb407d3","id":"456","name":"Dog pillow","price":25.99}]
```

I'm at a complete loss, really.

Comment: You've manually set an "id" field but Mongoose automatically creates an id virtual that references _id. I believe you have a conflict between that reference and your custom field. Aside from updating your collection, I'm not sure how you might resolve it.
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#id

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById) is what you're looking for. Visit the link for references, but here's a little snippet.

For the sake of this example, let's have a static id, even though Mongo creates a dynamic one [ _id ]. Maybe that what is the problem here. If you already a record in your DB with that id, there's no need for adding it manually, especially not the already existing one. Anyways, Drop your DB collection, and try out this simple example:

```
    // Search by ObjectId
    const id = "123";

    ToyModel.findById(id, (err, user) => {
    if(err) {
    // Handle your error here
    } else {
     // If that 'toy' was found do whatever you want with it :)
    } 
});
```

Also, a very similar [API](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne) is `findOne`.

```
 ToyModel.findOne({_id: id}, function (err, toy) { ... });
```

Comment: Thanks! Though, I think that this would need to be combined with @RevNoah's suggestion to set the schema object to `{id: false}`, since the `id` object was defined by the autograder/course, instead of being autogenerated. I believe that a lot of this error comes from sloppy code in the course I was taking. Thanks for your input!

Comment: `MongoDB` is generating this `_id: xoxoxoxox`. Emphasis on **`_`**. `Mongoose` is an `ODM` (object data modeling) library that provides a rigorous modeling environment for your data, enforcing structure as needed while still maintaining the flexibility that makes MongoDB so powerful. What that means, you decide which properties you need inside of you `Schema`. `id` can be one of them, but doesn't have to be. For the sake of the example, I typed in a static one, but it all depends on how **you** structured your app. Be creative with it. Good luck with your future learning. Happy hacking **;)**